skip check during simulation
I have a program that check for valid signature provided from the instruction's args before allowed to proceed execution.
The issue is how to allow the simulation to by pass the signature check to simulate the execution ?
Thanks

If you work in Typescript with @solana/web3.js library then you can pass the sigVerify parameter with the value false to skip the verification.
const response = await connection.simulateTransaction(tx, {
  sigVerify: false,
})

An example could be e.g., the Solana helpers code here:
https://github.com/solana-developers/helpers/blob/main/src/lib/transaction.ts#L50-L53
It's similar within Rust client as well.
